# Prove $\sin(kx)/x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I know that the infinite series

$$2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\sin(k x)}{k}=x \quad\quad \tag{1} $$

is the well known Fourier transform of $f(x)=x$. I would like to find upper bound for the partial sum of $(1)$, i.e.,

$$2\sum_{k=1}^{n}  (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\sin(k x)}{k} <C$$

It would be particurarly nice if I could find an uper bound of the form

$$2\sum_{k=1}^{n}  (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\sin(k x)}{k} <x+C$$

Comment: Its not the Fourier transform of $f(x)=x$, rather its the Fourier series for $f(x)=x$ on the interval $-\pi<x<\pi$.

Comment: It seems like you're asking for the maximum value of the overshoot near $x=\pi$ associated with the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What if we take x to be on the interval $0<x<\pi$? I would like to have a bound of the form $x+ O(\frac{1}{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a complete answer, but I believe it provides some insight.

---

I assume by "take $x$ to be on the interval $0<x<\pi$" in your comment you mean

$$f(x)=(x \bmod \pi)\tag{1}$$

which is approaximated by the Fourier series

$$f_n(x)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin (2 k x)}{k}\right)\tag{2},$$

but [Gibbs phenomenon-Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon#Description) indicates the following:

> "As more Fourier series constituents or components are taken, the Fourier series shows the first overshoot in the oscillatory behavior around the jump point approaching ~ 9% of the (full) jump and this oscillation does not disappear but gets closer to the point so that the integral of the oscillation approaches to zero (i.e., zero energy in the oscillation)."

---

The following plot illustrates $f_n(x)-f(x)$ where formula (2) above for $f_n(x)$ is valuated at $n\in\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32\}$ and the horizontal reference line is at $y=0.09\, \pi$.

[image: Illustration of f(x)-x]

Comment: The infinite sum in (2) gives $\frac{\pi -2x}{2}$, thus $f_n(x)=x$ in (2).

Comment: I just want to show that the finite sum is bounded by something that has degree $O(1)$ plus some $O(1/n)$ terms. I do not want to bound it with something that has $n$ at the numerator as i am working on an asymptotic problem and it will give me a bad approximation in the end.

Comment: @StefanosKomouris I'm not sure what you're looking for, but for the $2 \pi$-periodic Fourier series in your question the maximum deviations from $x$ over the interval $-\pi<x<\pi$ are $\pm\pi$ which occur at $x=\pm(-\pi+\epsilon)$ since the Fourier series converges to $0$ at $x=\pm\pi$, and the maximum and minimum values of the Fourier series are approximately $\pm 1.09\, (2 \pi)$ which occur near $x=\pm \pi$.

Comment: @StefanosKomouris For the $\pi$-periodic Fourier series in my answer, the maximum deviations from $x$ over the interval $0<x<\pi$ are $\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ which occur at $x=0+\epsilon$ and $x=\pi-\epsilon$ since the Fourier series converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ at $x=0$ and $x=\pi$, and the maximum and minimum values of the Fourier series are approximately $1.09 \pi$ and $-0.09 \pi$ which occur near $x=\pi$ and $x=0$.